# Processing - rotate multiple images by different amounts

Tags: processing

I am working with Processing's [`rotate`](https://processing.org/reference/rotate_.html) function.

I have a base image and then using `image()` I overlay two more smaller images on top.

I want to rotate image1 by x degrees and image2 by y degrees, but `rotate` only seems to be able to rotate both at the same time.

Is there a way around this? I thought of adding+rotating image1, saving the file, then adding+rotating image2 on top of the new file, but would prefer a more efficient way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely rotate images by different amounts, without going through the extra step of saving any files.

**Step 1:** First, you need to `translate()` to the center of the images. If they're all the same size then that's easy, otherwise you'll have to `translate()` to each center before drawing each image.

**Step 2:** Then just `rotate()` however much you want for each image.

**Step 3:** Finally, draw the image.

Repeat that process for each image, and it should work fine. But keep in mind that `translate()` and `rotate()` calls stack, so if you call `rotate(10)` and then call `rotate(15)`, that's like calling `rotate(25)`. To avoid this, you might use the `pushMatrix()` and `popMatrix()` functions. As always, [the Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/) is your best friend.

If you're still stuck, please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we'll go from there. Good luck.